# how to solve "Microsoft.graph.serviceexception code generalexceptionmessage an error occurred sending the request" while fetching calendar events?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I have created an auth provider using  user-password auth provider but and trying to retrieve calendar events in bot code which is in c#, having bot framework 4

```cs
IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication =
    PublicClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create("jhnjchdjvd")
        .WithTenantId("sdfdf")
        .Build();

var s = new SecureString();
s.AppendChar('<');
s.AppendChar('T');
s.AppendChar('N');
s.AppendChar('>');
s.AppendChar('7');

UsernamePasswordProvider authProvider = new UsernamePasswordProvider(publicClientApplication, scopes);

GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

Microsoft.Graph.User me = await graphClient.Me.Request()
    .WithUsernamePassword("kjkhv@indica.onmicrosoft.com",
        s).GetAsync();

var events = await graphClient.Me.Events
    .Request()
    .Header("Prefer", "outlook.timezone=\"Pacific Standard Time\"")
    .Select(e => new
    {
        e.Subject,
        e.Body,
        e.BodyPreview,
        e.Organizer,
        e.Attendees,
        e.Start,
        e.End,
        e.Location
    })
    .GetAsync();
```

Above code throws exception which is

> Microsoft.graph.serviceexception code generalexceptionmessage an error
> occurred sending the request

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Could you please check your redirect uri?

Comment: Check inner exceptions. That might give better clue.

Comment: Did you solved this?

Comment: @zendu no other details in inner exception

Comment: Make sure you use the latest NuGet Package and give a try. In order to get the latest one try the following: "Install-Package Microsoft.Identity.Client -Pre". This command installs latest MSAL library.

Comment: @Dev thanks I've tried this, but I got the same issue, I've also tried this https://www.schaeflein.net/aadsts7000218-public-client/

Comment: @Gerald, yes the error may happen when you not specified the "add mobile or desktop platform" in the authentication tab; also i noticed when you haven't specified the correct redirect URI as well.

Comment: Quickly [i tested the sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-windows-desktop). I  know its not the BOT framework, but its MSAL & calling Graph, so the same logic applies and works on the principles. It works for me. So i would suggest you to follow the steps specified and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: Let me move this to answer. So it can be useful to others as well. Please accept it as answer if it helps. Even if not, i will love to help further as well.

Comment: Also in the past [i tested with BOT Framework and MSAL. Here are the steps that i followed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv2%2Ccsharp). You may want to check the same as well.

Comment: Does it helped?

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure you use the latest NuGet Package and give a try. In order to get the latest one try the following:

> "Install-Package Microsoft.Identity.Client -Pre".
> This command
> installs latest MSAL library.

- Quickly i [tested the sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-windows-desktop). I know its not the BOT framework, but its MSAL & calling Graph, so the same logic applies and works on the principles. It worked for me.
- Also i tested with [BOT Framework and MSAL; here are the steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv2%2Ccsharp) that i followed. You may want to check the same as well.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue in my case was caused by revoking the `Task` function by `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.

Solution: I replaced the `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` with `await` approach.